# How to Validate two dropdown box focus using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to validate two dropdown boxes. if the dropdown is not selected it will alert the user to select the value from the dropdown. And it should focus the corresponding dropdown.
This is my code, some one

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>sample</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

function validator(theSelect)
{


  var bcolor = document.forms["register"]["bcolor"].value;
 if (bcolor == "") {
     alert("Please Select Your color1");
     return false;      
 }
  var bcolor1 = document.forms["register"]["bcolor1"].value;
 if (bcolor1 == "") {
     alert("Please Select Your color2");
     return false;       
 }
 if (theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].defaultSelected)
return true;
}
</script>  
<body>
<form method="post" action="sample.php" onSubmit="return validator(this)" name="register">
<select name="bcolor" size="1">
<option value="" selected="selected">Pick a Color</option>
<option value="rd">Red</option>
<option value="yl">Yellow</option>
<option value="gr">Green</option>
</select>

<select name="bcolor1" size="1">
<option value="" selected="selected">Pick a Color</option>
<option value="rd">Red</option>
<option value="yl">Yellow</option>
<option value="gr">Green</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: you have not written any code for 'focus'. Use focus() before returning false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `focus()`:

```
if (bcolor == "") {
     alert("Please Select Your color1");
     document.forms["register"]["bcolor"].focus();//
     return false;      
 }
  var bcolor1 = document.forms["register"]["bcolor1"].value;
 if (bcolor1 == "") {
     alert("Please Select Your color2");
     document.forms["register"]["bcolor1"].focus();//
     return false;       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workign [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/j2o82vwq/)

```
function validator(theSelect)
{
    var bcolor = document.forms["register"]["bcolor"];
    if (bcolor.value == "") {
        alert("Please Select Your color1");
        bcolor.focus();
        return false;      
    }
    var bcolor1 = document.forms["register"]["bcolor1"];
     if (bcolor1.value == "") {
         alert("Please Select Your color2");
         bcolor1.focus();
         return false;       
     }
     if (theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].defaultSelected)
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just ***call the focus() method*** on the target element.

After ur first alert
     // Code to focus the first dropdown(bcolor)
 ***document.forms["register"]["bcolor"].focus();***

After ur second alert
     // Code to focus the second dropdown(bcolor1)
 ***document.forms["register"]["bcolor1"].focus();***